# Request to Instagram works from Jupyter, fails in Airflow

Tags: python, python-requests, airflow, instagram-api

I'm doing a simple request of an IG post to see the total views. When I do this in jupyter, like so, I have no problems:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/CDjX7uAl0zg/?igshid=lcsk0qnidrcz')
r.content
```

This returns the content, ready to be parsed.

When I do this same request inside of a task in Airflow, the request returns no content. What gives?

EDIT: Adding my complete code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import logging

video_links = ['https://www.instagram.com/p/CDjX7uAl0zg/?igshid=lcsk0qnidrcz']

def get_data(video_links):
    for link in video_links:
    logging.info(link)
    r = requests.get(link)
    logging.info('Page...')
    logging.info(r.status_code)
    logging.info(r.content)
    logging.info(type(r.content))
    logging.info(r)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

get_data = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_data',
    python_callable=get_data,
    dag=dag
)

send_to_s3_and_redshift = PythonOperator(
    task_id='send_to_s3_and_redshift',
    python_callable=send_to_s3_and_redshift,
    dag=dag
)

get_data >> send_to_s3_and_redshift
```

Its very simple code. A list of IG links is passed, it then requests that link and parses the result. But `r.content` doesn't seem to exist. The crazy part is, the logging doesn't even work on this line:

```
logging.info(r.content)
```

Instead, it goes straight to the next line of logging and prints `str` as the type. The response code is 200, the type is str, but it won't print it or parse it. The only thing I can guess is IG is blocking airflow from making a request? But then I don't understand why it would respond with a 200 code and why it works fine locally

EDIT: Adding logging to show lack of r.content printing:

```
[2020-08-25 23:20:39,280] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2020-08-25 23:20:39,279] {_kondo_crowdtangle.py:74} INFO - https://www.instagram.com/p/CDjX7uAl0zg/?igshid=lcsk0qnidrcz
[2020-08-25 23:20:39,438] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2020-08-25 23:20:39,438] {_kondo_crowdtangle.py:76} INFO - Page...
[2020-08-25 23:20:39,439] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2020-08-25 23:20:39,438] {_kondo_crowdtangle.py:77} INFO - 200
[2020-08-25 23:20:39,439] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2020-08-25 23:20:39,439] {_kondo_crowdtangle.py:79} INFO - <type 'str'>
```

Comment: What is the status code of the response?

Comment: 200, but r.content has no data

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: Ok I shared my complete code. I've confirmed the video link is correct, the status code is 200. But there is simply no content. I don't understand at all

Comment: Try sending a well known user agent.

Comment: try passing op_kwargs={ 'video_links' : video_links } in your get_data task

Comment: In actuality, i've left out a little bit of code that generates the video links. The video links are there, i can log the array of them and see that I'm requesting properly. I tried user agents but it didn't work